# ruby Array.inspect vs. Array[element].to_s

Tags: ruby, linux, arrays, string

I'm working with an array, which we'll call `books`, of complex objects, which we'll call `Book`. The problem is when I call `puts "#{books.inspect}"`, ruby outputs a stream of binary (unreadable utf8 characters). However, when I call `puts #{books[0].to_str}"`, I get a brief, pretty output that describes the `book` in question. Not sure if it is relevant, but `Book` is a subclass (we can call it's parent class `Item`), and `books.length=1`

[Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html) implies that `.to_s` and `.inspect` are synonymous, but they are clearly providing different results in practice. Does anyone know why this is happening and can you provide a suggestion for how to get the nice output I want out of the whole books collection?

Misc info:

```
[chk ~ ]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: `#{code}` automatically calls `to_s` on whatever the return result of the code is. `#{books[0].to_s}` == `#{books[0]}`. `puts` does the same thing. So, `puts books[0]` == `puts "#{books[0].to_s}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Myclass
    def to_s
        'my string representation'
    end
    def inspect
        'my inspection'
    end
end
a= [Myclass.new]
p a
puts a

outputs ::
[my inspection]
my string representation
```

The inspect method is called for each element inside the array. If that method is not defined you get the default class representation. You will just need to define `inspect`.

You could always just do :

```
def inspect
  self.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`books.inspect` and `books[0].to_s` are absolutely NOT the same.
The first is a call to `inspect` method of `book` object, which is an array. The second is a call to `to_s` method of `books[0]` object, whatever it is that is contained inside the array.
As you didn't specify what exactly is `books[0]`, I'm afraid I can't tell anything more.

Comment: well books[0] is a Book, in which I have defined neither a `.inspect` nor a `.to_s` method. It's parent class, `Item`, has a `.inspect` method, but not a `.to_s` method. So I guess I still don't understand why `.inspect` fails but `.to_s` works..?

Answer (score 0):

`books` is an array so calling `books.inspect` is calling `Array#inspect`. That method works by calling `.inspect` on the elements, so in this case `Book#inspect`.

Doing string-interpolation `"Here's some info #{value}"` calls `.to_s` on the `value` object whatever its class may be.

Putting these together as an example `"Books #{books}"` would call `Array#to_s` (which is an alias for `Array#inspect`) that calls `Book#inspect` to produce the output string.

When you want things to work consistently, you should define `inspect` and make `to_s` an alias of `inspect` as is done in the `Array` class as an example. e.g.

```
class MyClass
  def inspect
    'my string representation'
  end
  alias_method :to_s, :inspect
end
```

There may be times when you want them to be different where `.inspect` is useful for debugging and `.to_s` for more usual output. In that case you would define each of them with different code.